# Switching from Nvidia to Intel upon login freezes

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

After updating my `addition drivers` to use `Nvidia-367.57` and `Intel CPUs from Intel-microcode` when I try switching in between them through `NVIDIA X Server settings` when I reboot using Intel's integrated cpu, upon login, I get stuck after I login. Mouse couldn't move, and cannot get into command-line with `Alt+Ctrl+F1`. So I had to manually switch it back by typing `sudo prime-select Nvidia`.

I have GeForce GTX 970M and the integrated intel HD 530 graphics card in my laptop. Running Ubuntu 16.10 alongside windows 10.

Anyone had similar issue and were able to solve it?

Appreciated
Thanks
- DC

EDIT: I've already tried upgrading my intel driver, but it doesn't work. I was able to load the login screen but after logging in, it shows my desktop wallpaper, and stuck from there on.

Comment: Tried installing Intel HD drivers?

Comment: Yes, I've tried installing it through Intel graphics for Linux, but still get stuck on the same part

Comment: What happens if after switching to Intel you log out/in?

Comment: When I switch to Intel, after trying to login, everything freezes. Have to force shut down to get to command line and switch back to Nvidia

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked. In your question you say you're switching, **rebooting**,  attempting to log in. I asked, 'switch, **log out**, log in'

Comment: Sorry for not being cleared in my post, at first I tried logging out then logging in, but it freezes. So I tried doing a restart, yet it still gives me the same freezing when typed in my password.